# cambiar display de un bloque al hacer click en un elemento clase y volver a cambiarlo al hacer segundo click

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos div que quiero mostrar u ocultar (uno oculto otro mostrado) si hacemos click en cualquiera de varios botones agrupados en una clase. Es decir, al hacer click en .enlaces debe cambiar el display de uno a "flex" y de otro a "none" y al hacer click de nuevo en .enlaces debe hacer la operación contraria (cambiar el display de uno a "none" y de otro a "flex"). Hasta aquí bien. Mi problema es que al hacer click por primera vez funciona pero ya no vuelve a hacer caso al evento.

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('enlaces');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
    var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(tres.style.display = "flex"){
            tres.style.display = "none";
            cuatro.style.display = "flex";
        }else{
            tres.style.display = "flex";
            cuatro.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

header nav{
    background-color:#262626;
}

header ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5%;
    width: 30%;
}

header li{
    color: white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.enlaces{
    text-decoration: none;
}

header img{
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
}

#absolute{
    width: 60%;
    padding: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: #3D3D3D;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

hr{
    border: 2px solid #262626;
    background-color:#262626;
    min-height: 10px;
}

#tres, #cuatro{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 2%;
}

#tres div, #cuatro div{
    width: 19.1%;
}

#tres h4, #cuatro h4{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 3% 0 3% 0;
}

#cuatro{
    display: none;
}

footer{
    background-color: #262626;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

footer p{
    padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>home</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>foo</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>blar</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>sudo</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>testimonials</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>contact</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img src="img/ancha.jpg" alt="cabecera">
                <div id="absolute">
                    <h3>Hello World</h3>
                    <p>- A blurlb about life would go well here -</p>
                </div>
        </header>
        <hr>

        <section id="tres">
            <div>
                <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                <h4>header</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                <h4>header</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                <h4>header</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="cuatro">
                <div>
                    <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                    <h4>header</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                    <h4>header</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                    <h4>header</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                    <h4>header</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        <footer>
            <p>Made for you by Alvaro Torres</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Como siempre, mil gracias

Comment: Puedes completar tu código con el html más? Ayudará a ejecutar el comportamiento dentro de esta página

Comment: hecho
Saludos
:D

Comment: Te falta un `=` para poder comparar, `if(tres.style.display == "flex")`. Y al principio `tres.style.display` es `""`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @x3k_js. A veces las torpezas hacen perder tiempo :D


Lo que no entiendo es lo que dices de: Y al principio tres.style.display es ""

Ahora que he solucionado esto solo funciona cuando doy un segundo click. En el primero no hace nada. Sabes por qué?

Gracias

Comment: Al ponerle el CSS de `display:flex` mediante el selector de `ID`, no se lo pones directamente al elemento, estas creando una regla css. Entonces si haces `document.getElementById("tres").style.display` te devolvera `""` (que implica que tiene el display de esa regla). Después del primer click, el `flex` se lo pones directamente al elemento (en el else) por lo que la comparativa si que es `true` y se cambian los displays. Para resolver esto puedes ponerle directamente el `style` en la etiqueta html, o tambien puedes hacer la comparativa con `==""` y en el else `tres.style.display = ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Faltaba un `=` para poder comparar:

```
if(tres.style.display == "flex")
```

---

Respecto al comentario:

> Lo que no entiendo es lo que dices de: Y al principio `tres.style.display` es `""` Ahora que he solucionado esto solo funciona cuando doy un segundo click. En el primero no hace nada.

Aunque tengamos una regla CSS que aplique un `display` para ese elemento, se puede ver como el `.style.display` devuelve `""`.

```js
console.log("Display: "+document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display);
```

```css
#myDiv{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  Asd
</div>
```

Esto NO significa que si `document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display;` devuelve `""` no se este aplicando un `display`, simplemente que JS no lo conoce, por lo que si hay una regla CSS se aplica esta.

Por lo que se podría volver a poner el `display:flex;` haciendo:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "";
```

```js
console.log("Display: "+document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display);

function toggleDisplay(){
    if(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display == ""){
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
        console.log("Display: "+document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display);
    } else{
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "";
        console.log("Display: "+document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display);
    }  
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle" onclick="toggleDisplay()">Toggle</button>
<div id="myDiv">
  Asd
</div>
```

---

Como se puede resolver en este caso:

- Ponerle el estilo CSS al elemento HTML `<section id="tres" style="display:flex;">`
- Comparar con `""` ya que das por hecho que se aplica el de la regla CSS y después en el `else` volver a poner el `display` por defecto `tres.style.display = "";`
- Comprobar la primera vez el computed style con **[getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)**

Comparación `getComputedStyle`, `currentStyle` para IE:

```
tres.currentStyle 
? tres.currentStyle["display"] 
: window.getComputedStyle 
? window.getComputedStyle(tres, null).getPropertyValue("display") 
: null;
```

**Snippet con `""`:**

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('enlaces');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
    var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
    links[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(tres.style.display == ""){
            tres.style.display = "none";
            cuatro.style.display = "flex";
        }else{
            tres.style.display = "";
            cuatro.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

header nav{
    background-color:#262626;
}

header ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0.5%;
    width: 30%;
}

header li{
    color: white;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.enlaces{
    text-decoration: none;
}

header img{
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
}

#absolute{
    width: 60%;
    padding: 1%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: #3D3D3D;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

hr{
    border: 2px solid #262626;
    background-color:#262626;
    min-height: 10px;
}

#tres, #cuatro{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 2%;
}

#tres div, #cuatro div{
    width: 19.1%;
}

#tres h4, #cuatro h4{
    text-transform: capitalize;
    margin: 3% 0 3% 0;
}

#cuatro{
    display: none;
}

footer{
    background-color: #262626;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

footer p{
    padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>home</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>foo</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>blar</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>sudo</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>testimonials</li>
                    </a>
                    <a class="enlaces" href="#">
                        <li>contact</li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <img src="img/ancha.jpg" alt="cabecera">
                <div id="absolute">
                    <h3>Hello World</h3>
                    <p>- A blurlb about life would go well here -</p>
                </div>
        </header>
        <hr>

        <section id="tres">
            <div>
                <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                <h4>header</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                <h4>header</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                <h4>header</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="cuatro">
                <div>
                    <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                    <h4>header</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                    <h4>header</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                    <h4>header</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="img/350x90.png" alt="">
                    <h4>header</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                            Ab dolorum a esse distinctio perferendis, iusto omnis cum eligendi architecto libero dolorem in recusandae odio nisi mollitia facere provident possimus aut.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        <footer>
            <p>Made for you by Alvaro Torres</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

### Relacionado SO

**[Respuesta SO (myDiv.style.display returns blank when set in master stylesheet)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16748905/11463270)**

**[Respuesta SO (What does style.display = "" actually do?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7420125/11463270)**

Comment: Perfecto!!
Muchísimas gracias por la explicación. Me ha quedado bien claro

:D